# Sourcing bashrc file fails with ssh -t

Tags: ssh, bashrc

```
ssh -vvv -F /home/me/.ssh/config serva -t "source ~/.bashrc"
```

This is the output I get when I use `-vvv` flag:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).                    
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]                          
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0                        
debug2: channel 0: send open                                     
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com                  
debug1: Entering interactive session.                            
debug3: Wrote 128 bytes for a total of 2413                      
debug2: callback start                                           
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0                              
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1                     
debug1: Sending command: source ~/.bashrc                        
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1                        
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY                                 
debug2: callback done                                            
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768             
debug3: Wrote 400 bytes for a total of 2813                      
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0               
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0             
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152                           
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0               
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0                       
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status rep
ly 0                                                             
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com
 reply 0                                                         
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow                                      
debug2: channel 0: close_read                                    
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed                          
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof                                      
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain                          
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty                                    
debug2: channel 0: close_write                                   
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed                        
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close                                    
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close                
debug2: channel 0: almost dead                                   
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user                               
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed                     
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close                                 
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close             
debug2: channel 0: almost dead                                
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user                            
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached                          
debug2: channel 0: send close                                 
debug2: channel 0: is dead                                    
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting                         
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1          
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cfd -1)         
                                                              
debug3: channel 0: close_fds r -1 w -1 e 6 c -1               
debug3: Wrote 32 bytes for a total of 2845                    
debug3: Wrote 64 bytes for a total of 2909
```

The server side log has the following message: `sshd[18763]: Received disconnect from` ...

I am using CentOS 6.4

#### Edit

My original question was flawed. Sorry about that. What I wanted to execute bash shell with the rc file I wanted (~/.bashrc_temp) and then execute something else. I think PROMPT_COMMAND is the recommended option it seems like, or having the command executed within ~/.bashrc_temp itself, which is less than ideal, but I can probably put some conditional statements.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? That output suggests it's succeeding and then terminating at the end of the command. I'm not sure what the goal of using `source` is here.

Comment: Also note that `bash` already interprets `~/.bashrc` when invoked over `ssh` (with and without `-t` and even when non-interactive like when passed a command like `source ~/.bashrc` (which causes `sshd` to run `bash -c 'source ~/.bashrc'`)).

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
ssh serva -t "source ~/.bashrc"
```

`ssh` tells `sshd` to invoke the login shell of the remote user as:

```
the-shell -c 'source ~/.bashrc'
```

That tells the-shell to run that command and exit.

Probably, what you want is to run an interactive shell and have that interactive shell to run that `source ~/.bashrc` command *and then* to issue a prompt and read more commands to execute from you.

First note that in the case of `source ~/.bashrc`, that's not needed since `bash` already sources your `~/.bashrc` when interactive (actually over `ssh`, it even does it when non-interactive). So:

```
ssh serva
```

Is enough.

Now, if you want to run a command and then an interactive shell, then you'd do:

```
ssh -t serva 'cmd; bash'
```

(there, the `-t` is needed as `ssh` doesn't start a pseudo-terminal by default when passed a command to execute)

`cmd` would not be executed by that `bash` though (it would be executed by the shell (your login shell there) started by sshd to interpret that `cmd; bash`
command line).

If you wanted that interactive `bash` to run that command. A trick is to use `bash`'s `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable. `bash` interprets the content of that variable as shell code to be executed before each prompt. So you can do:

```
ssh -t serva 'PROMPT_COMMAND="cmd; unset PROMPT_COMMAND" bash'
```

Comment: how can I run a command after executing bash? And I am hoping to keep the shell in session.

Comment: @Forethinker, you mean after `bash` has exited? `ssh -t serva 'bash; cmd'`

Comment: but then cmd does not get to run within the bash session that started.

Comment: If you want `cmd` to be executed by that `bash` then use the PROMPT_COMMAND method. Or do you mean that you want that `cmd` to be executed just before `bash` exits?